# zsh - variable assignment isn't working

Tags: zsh

I have this line in a function I'm adapting from a bash function into zsh function:

```
local info=( $(command df -P $fs | awk 'END{ print $2,$3,$5 }') )
```

Whenever I call it in the func I get this:

> mydf:9: bad pattern: info=( 712687280

But when I call it from the shell I get the expected answer:

```
$ info=($(command df -P $fs | awk 'END{ print $2,$3,$5 }'))
$ echo $info                                                                                      
712687280 166242288 25%
```

I am 2 days into zsh so I'm a little ignorant as to what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the assignment on a separate line from the `local` definition:

```
local info
info=( $(command df -P $fs | awk 'END{ print $2,$3,$5 }') )
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the separate line is needed? I see it is working on zsh 5.1.1 (Cygwin), but fails on 5.0.2 (Linux).

Comment: @AlexanderGroß when declaring and setting a local variable in a single command, apparently the order of operations is to first set the variable, and only afterwards restrict it to local scope. Try this:

Comment: local unexpected=$(exit 1) && echo $? # 0

Comment: local expected && expected=$(exit 1) && echo $? # 1