# Why does ZSH local variable assignment fail?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables

I was reading this question and answer: [zsh - variable assignment isn't working](https://superuser.com/questions/557741/zsh-variable-assignment-isnt-working).  The post explains how to fix it, but not why.  Why does the local variable assignment fail in that case ?

There are also some other examples of similar behaviour like this:

```
myfun()
{
local x=$(echo "a b"); echo ${x} 
}

myfun2()
{
local x 
x=$(echo "a b")
echo ${x}
}

myfun3()
{
local x=$(echo "a b")
echo ${x}
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
a
a b
a
```

If I put quotes around the 'x="$(echo "a b")" in all cases I get the correct variable assignment.

If I run the same thing in bash, I get 'a b' for all functions.

Can someone explain why bash and zsh are acting differently here ?

Answer (score 1):

<del>If you run your script with `-x` (both `bash` and `zsh`) you will see that the $(...) code gets interpreted/parsed differently. This is because, as [stated in the FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html), word splitting in zsh is backwards/bash/sh incompatible.</del>

<del>You can use `SH_WORD_SPLIT` to address this difference.</del>

Ok, so it is not a word split problem as we have a command substitution, quoting [the docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) again:

> ...If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken into words using the `IFS` parameter...

So your alternative is to `local IFS=""` :/

Comment: that doesn't seem to work:

`zsh -x test.sh

+test.sh:1> setopt shwordsplit

+test.sh:21> myfun

+myfun:2> echo 'a b'

+myfun:2> local 'x=a' b

+myfun:2> echo a`